# Python Class SQLite3 request returns object

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a database where I want to make a class called Employee, giving only the empid and getting the rest from a database.

```
    def__init__(self, empid):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("employee.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    self.empid = empid
    self.name = cur.execute("SELECT name FROM employees WHERE empid = " + str(empid))
    self.bday = cur.execute("SELECT bday FROM employees WHERE empid = " + str(empid))
```

Only it does not return the values, rather an object when I print it.

```
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x104687c00> <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x104687c00>
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Call `fetchone` after execute the query

```
cur.execute("SELECT name FROM employees WHERE empid = ?", (empid,))
self.name = cur.fetchone()[0]
cur.execute("SELECT bday FROM employees WHERE empid = ?",(empid,))
self.bday = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

but actuallly, this is better

```
cur.execute("SELECT name, bday FROM employees WHERE empid = ?", (empid,))
self,name, self.bday = cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: There we are! And on we go, you are very very much thanked Ursus! Do you have any idea how to unpack the tuple it returns in the same statement?

Comment: Note that you should pass a sequence of arguments as the second argument of `execute()`, not a naked string, so `(empid,)`. The whole `str()` wrapping is redundant when passing the args correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Python :)

Comment: @JoostvandenOever which script are you using?

Comment: @Ursus sqlite3, but I am intrigued by the people offering more options here

Comment: oh sure, ORM are awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`fetchone()`** to retrieve the first match of the query. This will return a `Row` object, by indexing (retrieving the first item with `[0]`), you then get the name so:

```
cursor = cur.execute("SELECT name FROM employees WHERE empid = " + str(empid))
self.name = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

But that being said, constructing queries such way is dangerous: it can result in [*SQL injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You better let `execute` escape the query properly:

```
cursor = cur.execute("SELECT name FROM employees WHERE empid = ?", (empid,))
self.name = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Since you fetch the name and bday of the two employees at the same time, you can also do this in one query, and then unpack it:

```
cursor = cur.execute("SELECT name, bday FROM employees WHERE empid = ?", (empid,))
self.name, self.bday = cursor.fetchone()
```

and it is advisable to use an ORM package (like SQLAlchemy or Django instead).